# Django Error when trying to add new HTML attributes in model form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this model

```
 40 class Item(models.Model):
 41     event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
 42     name = models.CharField('Item Name', max_length=50 )
 43     description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
 44     quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 45     start = models.DateTimeField('Availability Start Date', blank=True, null=True)
 46     end = models.DateTimeField('Expiry Date', blank=True, null=True)
 47     cost_price = models.DecimalField('Cost Price Per Item', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True, null=True)
 48     selling_price = models.DecimalField('Selling Price Per Item', decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, blank=True, null=True)
 49 
 50     def __unicode__(self):
 51         return u"%s" % self.name
```

And this model form

```
 39 class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
 40     description = forms.CharField(label='Description', max_length=250, widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
 41     image = forms.ImageField(label='Item Picture', max_length=50, required=False)
 42     start = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget, required=False)
 43     end = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget, required=False)
 55  
 56     class Meta:
 57         model = Item
 58         fields = ('image',
 59                   'name',
 60                   'description',
 61                   'quantity',
 62                   'start',
 63                   'end',
 64                   'cost_price',
 65                   'selling_price',
 66                   )
 67         widgets = {'cost_price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'onChange':'updateSellingPrice()'})}
```

I am trying to add a new attribute into the `cost_price` field that will in turn call a js function below:

```
  8 <script type="text/javascript">
  9     function updateSellingPrice() {
 10         $('#id_cost_price').change(function () {
 11             // get cost price
 12             var costPrice = $('id_cost_price').text();
 13             // set selling price
 14             $('$id_selling_price').val(costPrice);
 16         })
 17     }
 18 </script>
```

I'm getting this error when including line 67 `widgets = {'cost_price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'onChange':'updateSellingPrice()'})}` in my model form:

```
Exception Value: Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Could not import registration.views.item_details. View does not exist in module registration.views.
```

When I remove line 67 from my model form, everything works/loads fine. I think the Django error message is irrelevant as to what my actual error is. Off-topic: I find that errors in a forms.py file tend to raise error messages that put you on the wrong trail sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid. I was doing `from django.forms import forms` instead of `from django import forms`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create Forms from your Models and to customize them, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) is the oficial doc.

Use [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) to customize with HTML attributes